# Bash script: Using variables in executing sed in Freebsd which expects \ afters a

Tags: bash, shell, sed, scripting

I'm trying to use variables in a sed command in Freebsd. sed in Freebsd expects \ after a. Basically I want to append a line if a particular line in the file matches a pattern. I'm using sed's append for that.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

SYSLOG_SERVER="192.168.1.36"
SYSLOG_PORT="514"
syslog_conf_file="/etc/syslog.conf"
send_logs() {
    logs=(messages auth.log )
    send_logs[0]=`awk '(index($2, "messages") != 0) {print $1}' $syslog_conf_file`
    send_logs[1]=`awk '(index($2, "auth.log") != 0) {print $1}' $syslog_conf_file`
    for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#send_logs[@]} ; i++ ))
    do
        if [ ! -z "${send_logs[$i]}" ]; then
            send_logs[i]=${send_logs[i]}" \t"@$SYSLOG_SERVER:$SYSLOG_PORT
            sed  "/${logs[$i]}$/a\
            ${send_logs[$i]} \
            " $syslog_conf_file
        fi
    done
}
```

I'm facing this error. The variables are printed properly but the way in which I'm running the script is wrong. How can I fix this ?

```
root@Great# bash temp.sh
send_logs *.notice;authpriv.none;kern.debug;lpr.info;mail.crit;news.err \t@192.168.1.36:514
logs messages
sed: 1: "/messages$/a            ...": command a expects \ followed by text
send_logs auth.info;authpriv.info \t@192.168.1.36:514
logs auth.log
sed: 1: "/auth.log$/a            ...": command a expects \ followed by text
```

Sample expected input for sed:

```
root@Great# sed   '/messages$/a\                                      
 *.notice;authpriv.none;kern.debug;lpr.info;mail.crit;news.err @192.168.1.36:514 \
' /etc/syslog.conf
```

Expected output:

```
*.err;kern.warning;auth.notice;mail.crit        /dev/console
*.notice;authpriv.none;kern.debug;lpr.info;mail.crit;news.err   /var/log/messages
*.notice;authpriv.none;kern.debug;lpr.info;mail.crit;news.err @192.168.1.36:514 
security.*                  /var/log/security
auth.info;authpriv.info             /var/log/auth.log
```

Comment: sed isn't really designed to deal with variable expansion.

Comment: @RamanSailopal Oh, can't I fix this issue?

Comment: Please try and provide us with a [mcve], which I guess could be a single sed invocation that used the `a` command and a variable. Show us your input and the desired output.

Comment: @TomFenech Thanks ! I've modified the description with sample input and output and cut some files from the script.

Comment: I was thinking of something more like `var=foo` then showing a sample of the file before and after `foo` was inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `\` followed by a newline character means following line to be joined, to avoid escape : `\\` :

```
sed  "/${logs[$i]}$/a\\
        ${send_logs[$i]} \\
        " $syslog_conf_file
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean in your explanation but basically within double quotes, you need to use `\\ ` so that sed sees a single `\ `.

Comment: @TomFenech what I mean is that when there is a single backslash character at the end of a line the newline character is removed (except within single quotes)

Comment: Why do you think that it is removed?

Comment: because this is how read works and a simple example can demonstrate it, also reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html#Double-Quotes

Comment: Thanks for the link. As I understand it, it says that the backslash preceding the newline is removed, but it doesn't say what happens to the newline.

Comment: it's true that it's not said, if we look at the context (outside quote) there's also https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Escape-Character.html#Escape-Character which says